# Netgear FVS338 firewall and VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, netgear

I have a Netgear FVS338 Firewall and would like to be able to VPN into my home network.

I noticed Netgeaar has this VPN Lite/Professional. Do I need to use that or can I use something else?

I noticed you need a license but I bought this off EBAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VPN Lite license (1 user) comes bundled with the FVS338. Since you bought it off EBay chances are the device has been restored to factory settings. It may or may not have the license installed. If not, I would contact the seller to see if they have the activation key.

It appears you cannot purchase the VPN Lite license key separately. However, Netgear has this disclaimer up [here](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15066/~/vpn-lite-v4.66.012-%28supports-windows-7%29):

> For a limited time, customers who have purchased any hardware listed above after January 1st, 2010 may qualify to receive free VPN Lite license key.  You MUST show proof of purchase in order to qualify.  Click here to see if you are qualified to receive free VPN Lite license key.

You can try contacting Netgear support directly as well and explain your situation to see if they will give you an activation key.